# Why is this 404 Not found Error appearing and what to do about it?

Tags: php, docker, apache

I have ran into an issue with a PHP Apache Docker setup that is resulting in an error as shown below.

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.52 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8088

The current HTML path is as follows
C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\geo-project\geo-legacy\public\html

The docker files are inside of the geo-project folder and are as follows

version: "3.1"
services:

```
geo_legacy_sql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: geo_legacy_sql
    ports:
        - 3309:3306
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXX
        MYSQL_DATABASE: distanceManager
        MYSQL_USER: XXXX
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: XXXX
    networks:
        - default
    volumes:
        - geo-legacy-data:/var/lib/mysql

geo_legacy_phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: geo_legacy_phpmyadmin
    links:
        - geo_legacy_sql:geo_legacy_sql
    ports:
        - 8089:80
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: XXXX
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: XXXX
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXX
        PMA_HOST: geo_legacy_sql
        PMA_PORT: 3306

geo-legacy-api-v1:
    build: .
    container_name: geo_legacy_api_v1
    ports:
        - 8088:80
    volumes:
        - ./geo-legacy-v1/:/var/www/html/
    networks:
        - default
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
```

volumes:
geo-legacy-data:

With the respective

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/html/!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!/var/www/html/!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql bcmath sockets pcntl

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano wget
```

I have tried many things to fix this such as rearranging the directory and choosing new ports for the docker instance to run through.